# print and get training parameters (weights)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to print all weights and biases used in training step, as we can see in the code below https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/6_lstm.ipynb.  we have the variable v contains all parameters, I tried to print it but I hve NONE as result, I tried to use saver() and resrore but I can't read the checkpoint file

so is there any solution
thanks

---

Comment: Mmm, strange. As you can see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/optimizers you should have a list list of (gradient, variable) pairs. Variable is always present, but gradient can be None.
Can you update your question as to where you want to print the variable v?

Comment: yes I'd like to print v

Answer (score 0):

```
all_vars = tf.global_variables()
# just want to make sure all our variables are there!
for v in all_vars:
    v_ = sess.run(v)
    print("This is {} with value: {}".format(v.name, v_))
```